# getting success messages of SQL queries when executed from c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to run a sql query through c#. What I want is that when the query is executed then i should get the message that 1 row(s) affected. Also, I do not want the number because i want to run a procedure and there can be multiple queries in it.

Hence,

```
int rowsAffected  = comand.ExecuteNonQuery() // This wont work
```

My code is like this:

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\Projects;Initial Catalog=SprocSystem;Integrated Security=True;");
            string que = "insert into SprocParam values(1,'Int','Param5786',0,'desc')";


            conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;

            conn.Open();

            conn.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
            {
                textMessages += "\n" + e.Message;
            };

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(que, conn);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = command;
            da.Fill(ds);
```

Whenever there is a constraint error I get my corresponding output in textMessages variable like Primary Key Conflict. But, If the query is perfectly fine, textMessages is NULL. 
Instead what i want is the textMessage should contain that for which table how many rows got affected.

Can anyone help please.

I have to this for stored procedure hence i will not be able to modify the query. I just have the stored procedure's name.

Comment: Why doesn't `ExecuteNonQuery()` "work"?  Its return value *is* the number of rows affected.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, if i have multiple queries in the stored procedure, I want for each table how many rows got affected. Instead this will return the cumulative sum.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `@@ROWCOUNT` to achieve this, for example increase your query to:

```
insert into SprocParam values(1,'Int','Param5786',0,'desc')
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';
GO
```

More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Comment: I have to use a stored procedure. I will not have access to query in that case. Just the stored procedure name. Hence, I cant use this too.

Comment: You should add that requirement to your original question then.

Comment: sorry. I have added it now

Answer (score 2):

To be able to get the number of rows effected you must subscribe to the [`StatementCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.statementcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the command, the event arg has a property `RecordCount` that tells you how many records where effected for each statement.

```
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.StatementCompleted += sqlCommand_StatementCompleted;
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void sqlCommand_StatementCompleted(object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.RecordCount);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between using the `StatementCompletedEventArgs` vs the return value of  `ExecuteNonQuery`? When would you use one over the other?

Comment: You can't always use `ExecuteNonQuery()`, and in those cases you can fall back on the `StatementCompleted` event.   Clearly `ExecuteNonQuery()` is simpler and more obvious when it applies.

Comment: @MetroSmurf The event can be fired multiple times per execute, once per "# rows effected" you would see if you ran the query in management studio

Comment: Thanks @Stan and Scott. Had no idea that there was even a `StatementCompleted` event hanging off a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: How can i reterive print statements too between various queries written stored procedure

Comment: insert into SprocParam values(1 2,3,4);
select * from SprocParam;
print 'this is a test output'
delete from SprocHistory where SprocId = 2;

Comment: i need output as :(1 row(s) affected)
    
this is a test output

    (21 row(s) affected)
    

    (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: in order of print statements they are written

Answer (score 0):

If you have  SET NOCOUNT at ON, the ExecuteNonQuery returns 0. Try to set it to OFF.